# Multi-host deployment of ASP.NET Core applications

Tags: asp.net, iis, nginx, asp.net-core, load-balancing

I am quite confused as I haven't seen any blogs or instructions on how to host ASP.NET Core/.NET Core applications with HA and multi-host deployments. All examples are either:

```
1) One NGINX reverse-proxy, one Kestrel
2) One IIS reverse-proxy, one Kestrel
```

And both components on same host. In real-life production environments, you have LB maybe service discovery, multiple frontends, multiple backends, etc. But for this case there are no instructions whatsoever. So my questions would be for multi-host environments:

- Do I deploy one IIS/NGINX as LB/Reverse-proxy, and redirect requests to Kestrels running on many separate VM:s, i.e. various different IP:s?
- Or do I run an NGINX/F5 for load-balancing on one host, then route http traffic to various VM:s that run IIS+Kestrel, or just Kestrel? Is IIS required in this setup as NGINX acts as LB?
- If I run IIS or NGINX as reverse-proxy, can they keep alive Kestrels on different VM:s, or does each Kestrel require exactly one IIS/NGINX to keep it alive? I.e. the Kestrel process must be on the same same host as the reverse-proxy?

All answers are very welcome, and thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Hi. I don't have a complete answer to your question, but I can comment on the fact that in production, you wouldn't be handling requests on a VM just with Kestrel listening to requests, Kestrel needs an additional layer of  reverse proxy like IIS that will be able to handle application pool (relaunch Kestrel in case of a crash, recylcing...), handle client certificates, handle kerberos .... So always Kestrel + Reverse proxy. Good article: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS#RunningIISasaDevelopmentServer-no

Comment: Yes this is very clearly stated everywhere. The question is, what if I have many hosts :) as is always the case in production.

Comment: Hi, what was your solution regarding this? I am on the same situation. Please share your experience if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a setup with one VM using (IIS as LB) + several VMs with (IIS + Kestrel). It's working fine for my usage, but I'm curious to see if other people have different suggestions. Then it depends on what you are doing, if you use encryption, machine key needs to be shared between VMs, you might also needs to share session between VMs (https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/finding-and-using-asp-net-session-in-core-1-0/), store things in database ...

Comment: One proposal I would have is, to maybe leave out the IIS on the host where Kestrel resides on? It is not internet facing because you have an IIS before that, and you probably terminate SSL at the LB?

Comment: ... and sharing session is not a problem using SQL Server or Redis, which asp.net core supports out of the box.

Comment: I'm keeping IIS on all because, and that was the point of my first comment, let's say you have just Kestrel running on one machine, you'll get a process MyAspDotNetCoreApplication.exe running, but in case a crash happens in it, the IIS on this VM will be able to spawn a new instance, something the IIS running on another VM as a load balancer wouldn't be doing (unless you can find a way to do that and I would be very much interested in that).

Comment: I get your point, but the IIS most likely has an awful performance hit there. Probably also at the LB stage. Have you done comparisons between NGINX and IIS as LB? NGINX is very good at it, but I'm not sure about IIS LB capabilities. Is there a comparison somewhere? At least NGINX is able to stop routing messages to dropped nodes after max retries.

Comment: Hi. I haven't and would be interested in any feedback on the matter. All I can say, is that the performance are good enough for my need, and as far as I understood setting up IIS application pool with no need to bind a .Net Framework, just acting as a reverse proxy, seems quite efficient, Kestrel in itself being super fast, I end up having a setting easy to deploy and quite responsive. But you might have more performance concern than I do, and I haven't had the time to benchmark precisely everything against other LB for instance, but it's something I'd like when I can.

Comment: Do you use IIS ARR for load balancing? Do you like it? I have no experience, but I need an LB to route traffic to multiple VM:s hosting Kestrel (+maybe IIS). Does IIS ARR check if a node is alive and stop routing to it? Does IIS ARR allow you to configure routing strategy like NGINX does, e.g. route to least busy host, round-robin, etc.? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I'm using ARR, a setup close to what is described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSvbjfsitmU You can find different load balancing strategy: weighted round, weighted traffic, last current request, least response time ... And there is a monitoring tabs which checks if the server are healthy or not, I'm in the middle of doing my tests so I don't have all the answers yet, but it looks like it should do the job. Check it out, it's easy to setup.

Comment: Sounds good, you just saved me a day or two of investigation. Thanks! :)

Comment: No worries, I kind of like how IIS and ASP.Net Core can do together. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running NGINX at the edge as a load balancer and for SSL Termination and multiple servers with IIS + Kestrel serving MVC. This is working well for us. You may not need it but I've found NGINX to be quite a bit more sophisticated and powerful than anything you could do with IIS. Obviously F5 or something would work as well. Previously I also ran for a while using AWS ELB load balancers which also worked fine, just didn't have much configurability. So depends on your needs.

As was mentioned already, IIS is needed on each box running kestrel to manage the process. You could do this some other way, but using IIS is the easiest.

Comment: But isn't it still a bit unnecessary running IIS+Kestrel just for the sake of managing the process? I feel a good comparison for Asp.net Core+Kestrel would be Spring Boot (embedding Tomcat). With Spring Boot you run it in the same way as Asp.net Core. With Spring Boot, I would never run e.g NGINX on each host. I would simply have one NGINX as an LB, routing requests to many Spring Boot instances. In the same way, I would route NGIX/IIS to multiple Kestrels (and no IIS).

Comment: no, I wouldn't say its unnecessary, you have to use something to start the Kestrel process and to monitor it and restart it if something goes wrong. Sure IIS is a big overkill for this, but like I said its all setup with .net core module for this so its easy and I wouldn't worry about the performance, unless you have very high and unusual needs. There is nothing wrong with rolling your own solution to manage kestrel and then hitting it directly from NGINX, but why bother?