# How to configure multiple Kestrel Apps behind single IIS Reverse Proxy

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy

I have 1 Visual Studio Solution with 2 .NET Core Apps (Authentication / Authorization).

I can configure them to each use a separate `localhost:[Port]` and run both.
This results, as I understand in 2 IIS Reverse Proxy Instances, each with its own Kestrel App.

**How do I configure WebHostBuilder to host both under the same Reverse Proxy?  Do I keep 2 web.configs / new up 2 WebHostBuilders?**

Ultimate goal is to host on azure with 2nd app in a Virtual Directory.

The following are in the Main of BOTH projects.

```
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseUrls("localhost:5000")// Would like localhost:5000/virtDir
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
```

Comment: How did you resolve this as got similar issue?

Comment: I never solved this unfortunately.. Please let me know if you eventually do.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Still no, no longer have the requirement and moved on.

Comment: See this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42003404/505893